# Inno, NSIS, Wix: elevation or OS-version issues?

Tags: windows, installation

I'm in the process of deciding on a software installer package to use to deploy other people's applications in my small business environment. I'm favoring Inno Setup, but am also aware of NSIS and WIX. I have a couple of issues that I'd like to ask your opinion about.

I want to know if elevation is an issue with these tools. I want techs to be able to execute the .exe or .msi files that I create from %systemdrive% or a USB drive or a network drive.

Can I avoid the elevation prompt? Can I get my .exe or .msi file to ask for elevation immediately instead of waiting for unpacking and preparation?

Will I be able to execute my .exe or .msi file from an elevated command prompt using command line switches (eg, -silent) without that installer file causing an elevation prompt? Can I chain installers together when I am building or rebuilding a system?

Are all of these tools able to deal with the differences between XP and Win7 and 32 vs 64 bit without a lot of scripting checks on my part?

Thank you so much for your help.